# Is it possible to use QCustomPlot in unit testing?

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I need to create a family of plots during a test of my program. I want to use `QCustomPlot` for such purposes, but I have a problem. For creating and saving my plot in the file,  I have to create `QApplication`, after I need to reimplement my class from `QMainWindow` and after that, I can Use my `QCustomPlot` in the function that creates all needed plots and saves them in to file. Is it possible to avoid creating `QApplication` instance or `QMainWindow` instance or them both?

See code of my function below:

```
void MainWindow::print_image(std::vector<double> az, std::vector<double> el, std::vector<double> za, char *image_path){

QVector<double> azFunct;// =// QVector<double>::fromStdVector(az);
QVector<double> elFunct;// =// QVector<double>::fromStdVector(el);
QVector<double> zFunct = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(za);
QVector<double> xAxisValue(az.size());

//Filling axes of x with values
std::iota(xAxisValue.begin(),xAxisValue.end(),0);

QCustomPlot customPlot;

customPlot.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedKingdom)); // period as decimal separator and comma as thousand separator
customPlot.legend->setVisible(true);
QFont legendFont = font();  // start out with MainWindow's font..
legendFont.setPointSize(9); // and make a bit smaller for legend
customPlot.legend->setFont(legendFont);
customPlot.legend->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,230)));
// by default, the legend is in the inset layout of the main axis rect. So this is how we access it to change legend placement:
customPlot.axisRect()->insetLayout()->setInsetAlignment(0, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignRight);

//Adding new graph for displaying, all on the same plot.
customPlot.addGraph(customPlot.yAxis, customPlot.xAxis);
customPlot.graph(0)->setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 100, 0)));
customPlot.graph(0)->setName("Azimuth function");

//Adding new graph for displaying, all on the same plot.
customPlot.addGraph();
customPlot.graph(1)->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
customPlot.graph(1)->setName("Elevation function");

//Adding new graph for displaying, all on the same plot.
customPlot.addGraph();
customPlot.graph(2)->setPen(QPen(Qt::green));
customPlot.graph(2)->setName("Z-axis function");


for(int i = 0; i < az.size(); ++i){
    azFunct[i] = sin(az[i]*M_PI/180);
    elFunct[i] = cos(el[i]*M_PI/180);
}

double minZ = *std::min_element(zFunct.constBegin(), zFunct.constEnd());
double maxZ = *std::max_element(zFunct.constBegin(), zFunct.constEnd());

// pass data points to graphs:
customPlot.graph(0)->setData(xAxisValue, azFunct);
customPlot.graph(1)->setData(xAxisValue, elFunct);
customPlot.graph(2)->setData(xAxisValue,zFunct);

customPlot.xAxis->setVisible(true);
customPlot.xAxis->setTickLabels(false);
customPlot.xAxis2->setVisible(true);
customPlot.xAxis2->setTickLabels(false);
customPlot.yAxis2->setVisible(true);
// set ranges appropriate to show data:
customPlot.yAxis->setRange(-1, 1);
customPlot.yAxis2->setRange(minZ, maxZ);

customPlot.plotLayout()->insertRow(0);
//customPlot.plotLayout()->addElement(0, 0, new QCPTextElement(customPlot, "Z axis", QFont("sans", 12, QFont::Bold)));

// set labels:
customPlot.yAxis->setLabel("sin/cos value");
customPlot.yAxis2->setLabel("Z - axis");
//Under big question have to be tested!
customPlot.replot();
customPlot.savePng(QString(image_path),1500,500,1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't need a `QMainWindow`, you could instantiate a `QCustomPlot` instance by itself, not as a sub-widget of anything else. Furthermore, you don't need to show that widget to have it plot. So the tests can be non-interactive, even though they instantiate `QApplication`.

Of course, the design of `QCustomPlot` is broken; there's no need for it to be a `QWidget`. Only a particular view of a plot needs to be a widget. But that's another story.